# Why does my Qt app need libQt5Gui.so.5 when I don't use any GUI libs?

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I have a few qt apps, none of them use and GUI elements as far as I am aware. However one of these requires libQt5Gui.so.5 library when I am deploying it.

The main difference with this project is that I am using some multimedia libs:

```
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
```

The pro file for this project looks like this (I am explicitly removing the gui libs):

```
QT       += core
QT       += network
QT       += multimedia
QT       += xml
QT       -= gui

TARGET    = Rpe
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE  = app
```

Another pro file that does not need libQt5Gui.so.5 looks like this:

```
QT       += core
QT       += network
QT       += xml
QT       -= gui

TARGET    = Mvp
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE  = app
```

Does this mean that multimedia requires the gui libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that multimedia requires the gui libraries?

**Exactly**

It uses basic GUI classes like: `QImage`, `QMovie`, `QFont`, `QColor`, ...

And of course many others from the *Gui* module.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I find it strange since I explicitly remove the gui module (`CONFIG -= gui`)... I suppose multimedia over-rides this, I would have hoped for some error or warning.

Comment: In your *.pro* file you are removing the *Gui* module from **your** build process. But the *Multimedia* module was built with the `QT += gui`, so it needs the *Gui* module in the end.